# Add element in JSON without key identifier - FIREBASE

Tags: json, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure of my firebase database and the json file that I used to create that firebase structure.

[image]

"Menu" it's a list of ingredients, divided for categories, like "Pane" (Bread in english). "Pane" that has a field "lista" that have alle the type of breads (each type of bread has 3 fields: "attivo", "nome", "prezzo"). 
I need to ask the user to add a new ingredient, so to add a new element that has the fields "attivo", "nome", "prezzo".

The problem is that my sub ingredients (types of Breads) don't have an identifier, so I don't know how to add a children to "Lista" without an id key.

With this code (used in my typescript file) all the "lista" field it's replaces by the new element, and I can't use **.Child()** because I don't have an identifier to pass:

```
firebase.database().ref('/menu/pane/lista').set({ 
      nome: data['nome'],
      prezzo: data['prezzo'],
      attivo: false, 
});
```

Is it possible to add an element without have an identifier and have a situation like my json file?

**EDIT**
If I use set or push, my json structure change and I don't want that:
[image]
Thank you in advance.

**Solved**
I've solved the problem with a workaround. I retrieve the array that populate "lista" and push the new ingredient like in a normal array, than I push into "lista" on firebase the array with the new element. In this way all "lista" content it's replaced by the array that I push, but the array has the new element so it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would be possible to save the values into an array that you would store under the `lista` node, but this would create some "extra complexity". See this Firebase Blog post for more details: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

The recommended way to add some data to a list without having a (natural) uid is to use the `push` method: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push.

So, you should do as follows and Firebase will automatically generate a unique id for your new record:

```
firebase.database().ref('/menu/pane/lista').push({ 
      nome: data['nome'],
      prezzo: data['prezzo'],
      attivo: false
});
```

---

If you don't want the identifiers of your `pane` nodes to be auto-generated (as alphanumeric value like "-LStoAsjJ....") you would need to generate them yourself. But then you would have to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to generate this sequence, and this will add some complexity too. It is probably better to use `push()` and re-engineer your front end code in such a way you can deal with the alphanumeric uids generated by Firebase.

Comment: thank you for the help, but your code change my json structure (please check the added image to my question) and I would like to avoid that...

Comment: What do you mean by "your code change my json structure"? Do you mean that instead of a record identifier that is an integer you now have an alphanumeric (cryptic) value?

Comment: I mean that, as you can see in my first image, my ingredients into "lista" field don't have an identifier. I have lista = [{element1},{element2},..etc..] If I upload that json into firebase I obtain the structure that you see in the same image. 0, 1 etc are not identifier of the object but are the "position" that the element has into my "lista" field. If I insert a new element with push or set, an identifier for each element it's created and if I export my new json from firebase, the structure has change (like in the second image). This new structure is incompatible with my previous one.

Comment: Ok, I see. Indeed adding a node with an auto-generated uid in the list transforms the export from an array to an object. I don't think there is a solution if you want to use the export JSON feature from the Firebase console in this case. It all depends on what you exactly do with this JSON and why do you need to export it via the console (apart form "admin" purposes). You could get this data either through the JavaScript SDK or even through the REST API.

Comment: thank you for your time. I've solved the problem with a workaround. I retrieve the array that populate "lista" and push the new ingredient like in a normal array, than I push into "lista" on firebase the array with the new element. In this way all "lista" content it's replaced by the array that I push, but the array has the new element so it works!

Comment: Yes, this is one possible method, presented in the Firebase Blog post I referred to: the problem might be "concurrent updates from multiple clients". All the best with your Firebase developments.

Comment: Yes it's in the post that you've linked :D I'll accept your answer. Fortunately in my app only one user will change the data so I have no concurrency problems.